# npm debug breaks in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, chai, intern

I am trying to configure debugger for my Intern test(npm) project and it always fails with status

```
Process finished with exit code 130
```

I tried to do some research and got chai-fs causes some problem. But I am using chai framework.

Reference:
https://www.reddit.com/r/WebStorm/comments/43zbb6/exit_code_130_when_debugging_a_node_app/

I am using WebStorm 11 & node 6.2.2